# Difference between JumpTo and JumpBy?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to know the difference between methods JumpTo and JumpBy of cocos2D?
Where can I use JumpTo and where JumpBy?

please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JumpTo` will move the node to an exact point on the screen, but `JumpBy` moves by an offset relative to the current position of the node.

For example, lets say I have a sprite at point `30,30`. If I use `JumpTo` and specify `10,10` as the point the sprite will end up at `10,10`. If I use `JumpBy` and specify `10,10`, the sprite will end up at `40,40`.